# Confused why this javascript is causing me issues. Defined a class and prototype methods

Tags: javascript

I have the following which is a simplified version of what I have:

```
function MyClass(a,b) {
  this.a = a;
  this.b = b;
}

MyClass.prototype.f1 = function(a) {
    this.a = a;
};

MyClass.prototype.f2 = function(a) {
    this.f1(a);
};

var mc1 = new MyClass(1,2);
```

Now I am getting an error saying:

```
this.f1 is undefined
```

If I move f1 out to its own function, there error is gone.

What could be causing this problem?
I know if you run the simplified version above it should work, but what could be causing the issue in my codebase?  (I can't post it here, but any hints on what to look for?)

**Update**

Ok after tracing it in firebug, it seems the keyword 'this' has been rebound somehow and it is no longer bound to the class MyClass, hovering over it is shows 'function'.

What happened is that I set this function MyClass.f2 as a callback to Telerik editor, and it has somehow changed the scope of 'this'.

**What are my options to fix this?**

Comment: works for me.. in what browser/environment are you experiencing this error?

Comment: my guess is your code differs in some way from this simplified version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to refactor your code to a version that avoids using the `prototype` property:

```
function MyClass(a, b) {
    var t = this;

    t.f1 = function(a) {
        t.a = a;
    };

    t.f2 = function(a) {
        t.f1(a);
    };

    // constructor code...
    t.a = a;
    t.b = b;
}
```

This way you have a persistent reference to the current instance that you can use instead of the `this` keyword.

Comment: Well I am passing myIntance.f2() to editor control (telerik) as a callback to an event that the editor fires.  this won't work then right?

Comment: Yes, it would work - because your current problem is, that you're using `this` to identity the instance, but `this` gets reassigend by Telerik. The provided solution stores a reference to the current instance in a private variable `t` that Telerik won't (and can't) override.

Answer (score 0):

As you mention everything looks fine.  There are a couple of possibilities

1)  You defined a 'subclass' of `MyClass` and didn't hook up the prototype/constructors correctly.
2)  You might have changed the definition of the `MyClass` object (i.e. class) at runtime, so it wouldn't work after a certain point (yay dynamic languages)
3)  You trying to invoke `f1` from something that is not a `MyClass` instance.

without seeing the invocation that is causing the issue, and the surrounding code, I can't say more.

Comment: ok I think I got it, 'this' seems to be have redefined to the function and not the class MyClass.  What are my options?